# DNN - Is it a good idea to use grayscale images instead of RGB for training

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, object-recognition

I am trying to train a DNN for a purpose of object detection (vehicle detection and recognition). Since the colors does not matter for recognition, is it a good idea to use grayscale images for training?

This is likely to have the following benefits:

1. reducing the input dimension results in faster train and test.
2. removing the redundant information results in more general models.

Answer (score 2):

In general I think you can be right but probably having color can help the network to achieve better results on this given task.
I think the grayscale can work and be less computationally heavy to train, but the network trained on the RGB images can achieve better results, it is a tradeoff and depend on what you are looking for. 
When dealing with deeplearning the best thing you can do is just try after making your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea, considering your model might otherwise perhaps learn correlations that are detrimental to the task at hand(e.g. perhaps your testset only contains red ferraris, you might not recognise one of another color).